# Сохарнить из Excel в JSON

Tags: c#, json, excel

Всем привет! Нужно сохранить данные из нескольких Excel файлов в один JSON. Подскажите как сделать чтобы данные дописывались, а не перезаписывались?
И как можно проверить на null каждую колонку Excel файла?

```
        var data = "new.json";
        
        Workbook wb1 = new Workbook("1.xlsx");
        wb1.Save(data, SaveFormat.Json);

        Workbook wb2 = new Workbook("2.xlsx");
        wb2.Save(data, SaveFormat.Json);
```

Comment: Скорее всего необходимо самому считать excel файлы, обработать значения, превратить в единый json и сохранить в файл. [Newtonsoft (Json)](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json), [EPPlus (Excel)](https://russianblogs.com/article/14121580618/)